# How add a remove product icon(x) on woommerce checkout page?

Tags: woocommerce

I would like to add a remove product icon(x) on woommerce checkout page products because I’m going to send my users straight to checkout page and avoid the cart page. So what I want is that users can still have the option to remove any product they don’t want.

Thanks.
Pepe

Answer (score 0):

```
Add the following code to review-order.php in <thead> and <tbody> sections

<thead>

<tr>

<th class="product-remove"><?php _e( 'Remove', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>

</tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

<td class="product-remove">

<?php

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(

'<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',

esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),

__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),

esc_attr( $product_id ),

esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )

), $cart_item_key );

?>

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Filter :

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'njengah_filter_wc_cart_item_remove_link', 10, 3);

function njengah_filter_wc_cart_item_remove_link($product_name, 
   $cart_item, $cart_item_key)
{

if (is_checkout()) {

    $product_name .= apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" class="remove remove-icon" style="float:left;">x</a>',
        esc_url(WC_Cart::get_remove_url($cart_item_key)),
        __('Remove this item', 'woocommerce'),
        esc_attr($cart_item['product_id']),
        esc_attr($cart_item['data']->get_sku())
    ), $cart_item_key);

    return $product_name;
  }

}
```